# COMO RELACIONAR PAÍS, MONEDA, TIPO DE CAMBIO?

Tags: mysql, sql

Para un sistema que cuenta con países cada país contiene una moneda por defecto pero también puede trabajar con otras monedas asignadas, luego se asigna un tipo de cambio a cada moneda con la que trabaja ese país.

Ejemplo:
país: mexico,
moneda principal por defecto: peso mexicano,
moneda opcional: dolar americano;
moneda opcional: euro;

tipo de cambio
euro
dolar

mi tabla esta bien relacionada?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No le veo necesaria la relación a `tipo_cambio` con `paises`... 1 euro no deja de ser 1 euro si me voy a Indonesia

Comment: claro eso es correcto, 
pero siempre teniendo el ejemplo con mexico 
 1 euro = 500 pesos mexicanos
1 dolar = 480 pesos mexicanos.

como seria las relaciones de las tablas?

Gracias.

Comment: Y por qué quieres almacenar la conversión ?, Sabiendo que eso es un valor volátil y nunca será el mismo

Comment: Hola BetaM, quiero registrar el tipo de cambio para luego tener la información
**Ejemplo: 1 cuaderno esta 1 dolar pero el cliente pago en pesos = 480 pesos.
entonces como el tipo de cambio cambia a cada hora , cuando haga mi informe quisiera saber cual fue el tipo de cambio en el momento que se registro la venta.**